# Which of these algorithms will involve the least amount of math?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, linear-algebra

I'm taking an algorithms class for my computer science degree, and one of the requirements is to research and present 3 different algorithms. The only problem: linear algebra wasn't a prerequisite to the course.

Which of these algorithms would be the easiest to understand with the littlest math background? I plan on going through MIT's linear algebra course posted on YouTube as a crash course.

1. FFT for matrix multiplication
2. Metropolis Algorithm for Monte Carlo
3. Google PageRank
4. MapReduce
5. Simplex Method of Linear Programming
6. Fast Multiple Method
7. The Decompositional Approach to Matrix Computations
8. QR Algorithm for Computing Eigenvalues

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I would say the metropolis (even though im not familiar with it) is the best choice if you don't know linear algebra but you are familiar with probability theory

Comment: I assume #6 should be "Fast multip**o**le method"? Side remark: As a retired software engineer with a CS degree, I think it will be hard to avoid linear algebra in a CS-centric career, might as well dive in now.